# Использование Cookies в desktop-приложении

Tags: http, desktop, java, swing

Есть десктопная программа, которая общается с сервером через HTTP. Написана на Java+Swing. В программе пользователь может ввести своё имя и пароль и войти в систему. Хочу добавить галочку "Запомнить пользователя". Для этого нужно, чтобы мы могли оперировать с куками. Когда юзер делает операцию "логин" (post-запрос к серверу) в ответе содержится кука с айдишником открытой сессии. Как лучше всего обращаться с куками в desktop-приложении? Как лучше всего реализовать запоминание пользователя между запусками программы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу посоветовать вот этот [пост](http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?p=490) в блоге. От Андроид там только класс Log. Все остальное работает и так.
Запоминание пользователя весьма нетривиальная задача. Сколько не смотрел программ на Джава для работы с сервисами (например банкингов) никто и никогда не делал запоминание логина и пароля (разве что только логина). Как вариант храните в виде хэша, необходимого для произведения авторизации (если она основана на передаче хэш, хотя я бы не советовал, на сегодняшний день, к счастью, есть другие методы авторизации).

Comment: А что есть "в виде хэша, необходимого для произведения авторизации (если она основана на передаче хэш"? Как-то интересно звучит :). Или вы храните данные, необходимые для аутентификации - и их можно украсть, или нет (допустим вас пускают без пароля и от вашего имени может зайти злодей).

Comment: Не до конца понял вторую часть комментария.
Так называемая система аутентификации "Challenge response". Реализована быть она может в различных модификациях. В том числе и посредством передачи логина + хеш(пароля).